# How to make a symbol more boldface within a boldface section heading

Tags: bold

I have the following section heading:

```
\section{The system M of Minimal Logic}
```

which of course is all rendered in boldface in the pdf. How can I make the "M" even more boldface within this heading?

Comment: This might also help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable

Comment: I would simply do `\section{The system \emph{M} of Minimal Logic}`...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a font with more weights than just regular and bold. One such font is Adobe Serif Pro. But there are many and some have packages. If there isn't a package, then I'd use `fontspec` since it's easy to load arbitrary fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sourceserifpro}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\ifxetex
  \section{The system {\sourceserifproextreme\bfseries M} of Minimal Logic}
\else
  \section{The system {\fontseries{k}\selectfont M} of Minimal Logic}
\fi
This is regular weight.
\end{document}
```

[image]