# Weight of boldsymbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a way to change the weight of `boldsymbol` used in math mode? This is possible in [text mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable).

Comment: exactly the same answer applies, it just depends if you have a font available in more than one weight. However there are very few bold math fonts so having it available in multiple weights is even rarer. the only one I know is mathtime which has bold and heavy

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [Minion Math](http://typoma.de/en/fonts.html) has regular, medium, semibold, and bold.