# Removing non-black background from picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using a black background rectangle for a diagram, but cannot seem to get all the remaining white removed, I am mainly using overleaf to test my image.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, backgrounds, calc, shapes.misc, positioning}
\begin{document}
% Finish off green box and then browser outline tmmr
\tikzset{
    purpleBox/.style n args={3}{
        text centered, fill=purpleVue, minimum width = #1, minimum height= #2, text=white,
        text width = #3,
        rounded corners
    },
    redBox/.style n args={3}{
        text centered, fill=redVue, minimum width = #1, minimum height= #2, text=white,
        text width = #3,
        rounded corners
    },
    orangeBox/.style n args={3}{
        fill=orangeVue, minimum width = #1, minimum height= #2, text=white,
        text centered,
        rounded corners
    },
    greenCircle/.style n args={3}{
        fill=greenVue, minimum width = #1, minimum height= #2, text=white,
        text centered,
        circle
    },
    lineCustom/.style={
        very thick, 
        color=gray,
        dotted,
        shorten <=2pt,
        shorten >=2pt
    },
    arrowCustom/.style={
        >=triangle 60,
        ->,
        very thick, 
        color=gray,
        dotted
    },
}
\definecolor{purpleVue}{rgb}{0.6,0.5,0.9}

\definecolor{orangeVue}{rgb}{0.975,0.7,0.2}

\definecolor{greenVue}{rgb}{0.15,0.65,0.4}
\definecolor{redVue}{rgb}{0.95,0.45,0.55}
% Hardcoded positioning
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=black}, show background rectangle]

% Browser Box that wraps around UI and Client Addons box
\node[rounded corners, draw,
double=redVue, %% here
double distance =1pt, minimum height= 9.5em, minimum width=27em, dashed] 
(Browser) {};

% Label for browser
\node[rounded corners,
text=redVue] at ([xshift=-3em, yshift=4em]
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable
Browser.west) (BrowserLabel) {\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Browser};
% Green box in upper left
\node[rounded corners, fill=greenVue, text=white, minimum height= 7.5em, minimum width=10em, text centered, right = 0.75em of Browser.west] (UI) {User Interface};

% Purple box in upper right
\node[rounded corners, %fill=black,
text depth = 5em, minimum width=15em,
draw,
double=purpleVue, %% here
double distance =1pt,    %% here
%font=\Large, 
minimum height= 7.5em,
text=purpleVue, right = 0.5 em of UI]  (CA){Client Addons};
% Hardcoded nodes
\node[purpleBox={6em}{1.5em}{6em}] at ([xshift=-3.5em] CA.center){Injection};
\node[purpleBox={6em}{1.5em}{6em}] at ([xshift=3.5em] CA.center) (Mix) {Mixins};
\node[purpleBox={6em}{1.5em}{6em}] at ([xshift=-3.5em, yshift=-2em] CA.center) (comp) {Components};
\node[purpleBox={6em}{1.5em}{6em}] at ([xshift=3.5em, yshift=-2em] CA.center) (routes) {Routes};

% Mix is used as an example node to use offset
% \node[rounded corners, fill=greenVue, text=white, minimum height= 7.5em, minimum width=10em, text centered, right = 0.75em of Mix] (UI2) {User Interface};


% Node Js Box
\node[rounded corners, draw,
double=redVue, %% here
double distance =1pt, minimum height= 45em, minimum width=27em, dashed, below = 5 em of Browser] 
(Nodejs) {};
% Label for browser
\node[rounded corners,
text=redVue] at ([yshift=-14em]
BrowserLabel.south){\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Node.Js};

\node[rounded corners, %fill=black,
text depth = 5em, minimum width=15em,
draw,
double=redVue, %% here
double distance =1pt,    %% here
%font=\Large, 
minimum height= 10.5em,
minimum width= 25em,
text=redVue] at ([yshift=-6.5em]
Nodejs.north) (BProcess){};

% Label Node, seperate node is used
% to have control over node positioning
\node[text=redVue] at ([yshift=-1.5em]
BProcess.north) {\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Build Process};

\node[purpleBox={5.75em}{7em}{5em}] at ([xshift=3.25em, yshift=-0.5em] BProcess.west) (devStatic){DEV/Static Server};


%% WEBPACK CODE
% Sample label label={[anchor=north, draw=red, inner sep=0pt, yshift=-0.2em]north:Webpack}
\node[orangeBox={5.75em}{7em}{5em}, label={[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, yshift=-0.6em, text=white]north:Webpack}] at ([xshift=6.15em] devStatic.center) (webpack) {};

\node[purpleBox={4.5em}{3em}{4.5em}] at ([yshift=-0.5em] webpack.center) (webpackPlugin) {Webpack Plugin};

% MARKDOWN IT BOX
\node[orangeBox={6.75em}{7em}{5em},label={[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, yshift=-0.6em, text=white]north:markdown-it}] at ([xshift=6.75em] webpack.center) (markdownIt) {};

\node[purpleBox={5.25em}{3em}{5.25em}] at ([yshift=-0.5em] markdownIt.center) (webpackPlugin) {markdown-it plugin};

\node[purpleBox={3.75em}{7em}{3.75em}] at ([xshift=2.7em] markdownIt.east) (dynMod){Dynamic Modules};


% USER PROJECT
\node[rounded corners, %fill=black,
text depth = 5em,
draw,
double=redVue, %% here
double distance =1pt,    %% here
%font=\Large, 
minimum height= 13em,
minimum width= 15em,
text=redVue, label={[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, yshift=-1.2em, text=redVue] north:{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont User Project}}] at ([xshift=-2cm, yshift=-10.5em]
BProcess.south) (UP){};

% Configuration Files and Plugin box
\node[purpleBox={8em}{3.75em}{8em}] at ([xshift=5em, yshift=2em] UP.west) (confFiles){Configuration Files};

\node[greenCircle={2em}{2em}{2em}] at ([xshift=3em] confFiles.east) (CFP1){Plugin};

\node[redBox={8em}{3.75em}{8em}] at ([yshift=-3em] confFiles.south) (markFiles){Markdown Files};

\node[greenCircle={2em}{2em}{2em}] at ([xshift=3em] markFiles.east) (CFP2){Plugin};

% THEME BLOCK 
\node[rounded corners, %fill=black,
text depth = 5em,
draw,
double=redVue, %% here
double distance =1pt,    %% here
%font=\Large, 
minimum height= 13em,
minimum width= 15em,
text=redVue, label={[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, yshift=-1.2em, text=redVue] north:{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Theme}}] at ([yshift=-7.5em]
UP.south) (theme){};

% Configuration Files and Plugin box
\node[purpleBox={8.75em}{3.75em}{7em}] at ([xshift=5em, yshift=2em] theme.west) (tconfFiles){Configuration Files};

\node[greenCircle={2em}{2em}{2em}] at ([xshift=3em] tconfFiles.east) (tCFP1){Plugin};

% Figure out non hacky way
\node[redBox={8.75em}{3.75em}{7em}] at ([yshift=-3em] tconfFiles.south) (tLayoutComp){Layout Components};

\node[greenCircle={2em}{2em}{2em}] at ([xshift=3em] tLayoutComp.east) (tCFP2){Plugin};

% Plugin API
\node[purpleBox={5em}{25em}{5em}] at ([xshift=9.5em, yshift=-17.5em]
BProcess.south) (pluginAPI){Plugin API};


% Paths
% \path[color=white] (pluginAPI) -- (dynMod);
% Make path style
% latex'-
% \draw[->,>=latex,very thick, color=gray,dotted] (pluginAPI) -- (pluginAPI |- dynMod.south);
\draw[lineCustom] (pluginAPI) -- (pluginAPI |- dynMod.south);

\draw[lineCustom] (CFP1) -- (CFP1 -| pluginAPI.west);

\draw[lineCustom] (CFP2) -- (CFP2 -| pluginAPI.west);

\draw[lineCustom] (tCFP1) -- (tCFP1 -| pluginAPI.west);

\draw[lineCustom] (tCFP2) -- (tCFP2 -| pluginAPI.west);

\draw[arrowCustom] (devStatic) -- (devStatic |- UI.south) node [midway, left, yshift=2em] {Assets};

% Super advanced arrow

\draw[lineCustom, rounded corners=5pt] (dynMod) |- ($(comp.south) + (0, -4.5em)$) node[above] {MetaData};

\draw[arrowCustom, rounded corners=5pt] ($(comp.south) + (0, -4.5em)$) -| ( $(UI.south) + (3em, 0)$);

\draw[lineCustom, rounded corners=5pt] (devStatic.south) |- ($0.5*(dynMod.south)+0.5*(pluginAPI.north)$);

\draw[lineCustom, rounded corners=5pt] ($0.5*(dynMod.south)+0.5*(pluginAPI.north)$) -| ($(routes.south) + (3.35em, -4.5em)$);

\draw[lineCustom, rounded corners=5pt] ($(routes.south) + (3.35em, -4.85em)$) |- ($(routes.south) + (0, -3.23em)$);

\draw[arrowCustom, rounded corners=5pt] ($(routes.south) + (0.25em, -3.23em)$) -| (CA.south);

% Webpack to end line below
\draw[lineCustom, rounded corners=5pt] (webpack.south) |- ($0.5*(dynMod.south)+0.5*(pluginAPI.north)$);

\draw[lineCustom, rounded corners=5pt] (markdownIt.south) |- ($0.5*(dynMod.south)+0.5*(pluginAPI.north)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know it's kinda hard to see the white but it is definitely there on overleaf.

[image]

Note::
also tried to recreate picture from https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/.

[image]

Comment: Use `\documentclass[tikz,11pt]{standalone}` (instead of `\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}`). This will then make sure that the boundaries of the `tikzpicture` are used. Alternatively you can move `\begin{document}` after `\definecolor{redVue}{rgb}{0.95,0.45,0.55}`. The reason for the white area is not `tikz` but some spurious spaces in the commands before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Move `\begin{document}` to immediately before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.