# How can I use the xfakeboldness package?

Tags: fonts, bold

I'm interested in reproducing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445173/183821) using the `xfakebold` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfakebold}

\newcommand{\fbseries}{\unskip\setBold\aftergroup\unsetBold\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setBoldness}[1]{\def\fake@bold{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is some regular text.

% Default boldness = 0.3
This is some {\fbseries fake bold} text.

\setBoldness{0.5}%
This is some {\fbseries fake bolder} text.

\setBoldness{1}%
This is some {\fbseries fake boldest} text.

\end{document}
```

However when I attempt to reproduce in Overleaf or Sublime Text, I get:

[image: failed-boldness]

Which is not the expected result. How can I get the expected outcome as shown in the question?

Comment: Is there or do exists `xfakebold` package into Overleaf? I have compiled your MWE with MikTeX and it works correctly.

Comment: works ok for me with pdflatex and lualatex. How are you compiling and is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings? Something in the log? Do you compile with `--interaction nonstopmode` by any chance (which allows LaTeX to continue after an error, but with possibly wrong output)?

Comment: I found that this that this builds correctly only lualatex but not pdflatex. I get no errors or warnings using pdflatex.

Comment: How can I tell if my system is up to date? I downloaded my distribution only a few months ago, I think it should be okay -- but i'd like to confirm

Comment: However the _real_ document I want to build doesn't work with lualatex, only xelatex under the error `Font \T1/cmr/m/n/12=ecrm1200 at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. `

Comment: The `xfakebold` package does not work with XeLaTeX. You should get a warning in that case: "No LuaTeX or PDFTeX running! For Xe(La)TeX use the FakeBold option from package fontspec!" This is because the package uses PDF literals, which are not supported in this way by XeLaTeX.