# Bold instead of bold extended for `\boldmath`

Tags: math-mode, fonts, bold

Alas, yet another question on font selection in mathematics.

I want to avoid bold extended and use bold instead. My main font is computer modern. For text, I managed to change the appearance of bold with the help of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27843/27717). Also, changing the font for `\mathbf` wasn't to hard. But how can I make `\bm` or `\boldmath` match the rest of the fonts?

M(n)WE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bm}
% Bold in text.
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
% Bold in \mathbf
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{lmr}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfit}{OT1}{lmr}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbxit}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{it}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text: 
            \textbf{bold BOLD}
        \item \texttt{mathbf}:
            $\mathbf{bold BOLD}$
        \item \texttt{mathbfit}:
          $\mathbfit{bold BOLD}$
        \item \texttt{mathbxit}:
           $\mathbxit{bold BOLD}$
        \item \texttt{bm}:
            $\bm{bold BOLD}$
        \item \texttt{boldmath}:
        {\boldmath $bold BOLD$.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that the last two examples show much wider characters than the other examples. In fact, even wider than in the `\mathbxit`-example.

How can I get the same bold-non-extended letters in `\boldmath`? Plus: is there a non-extend bold version of `\mathcal`-letters?

[image]

Comment: the fact that `\bm` outside math mode is not raising an error is an oversight, it is not intended to do work in that context.

Comment: your final two examples are not clear, you are making bold roman use b not bx, but in the bold math you are using math italic and not showing an example of `\mathrm`  the math italic letters are by default `\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {bold}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}`  so already using b not bx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please consider my edit. I hope that makes clearer what I want to do.

Comment: but you should compare the bold math italic against the normal weight math italic (which you are not showing) math italic has wide sidebearings so adjacent letters look like a product of variables not a word.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The letter spacing is not what I am confused about, but about the fact that the "O" in the `bm`-example is wider than the "O" in the `\mathbxit`-example (at least, it seems), and both are much wider than the `mathbfit`-O.

Comment: cm only has one style of math italic bold (which is classed as b in latex) even if some of the letter shapes are wider. I think lm is the same but I'd have to check... yes look at omllmm.fd, the math italic bold is declared as `\DeclareFontShape{OML}{lmm}{b}{it}{%` with a substritution `\DeclareFontShape{OML}{lmm}{bx}{it}%
     {<->ssub*lmm/b/it}{}`  so b and bx are the same thig

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there an overview of all the math fonts and versions etc. available (for cm and lm)?

Comment: Look in base fd files for cm, or in /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/  (or an equivalent directory in your tex inputs) for the lm fonts known to latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do I interpret `omllmm.fd` correctly if I read it as there is only `n` and `bx`, and `b` is only a synonym for `bx`, but there is no lighter version of boldness?

Comment: actually it's coded as only n and b, with bx being a synonym for b, but either way yes there are only two styles

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the bold math variant

```
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr} {b}{n}
```

Thi swill affect operators like `\log` and `\mathrm` generally and make it use bold rather than bold extended.

The bold math italic font in your last example is wider as math italic has wide sidebearings to make adjacent letters appear as a product of variables rather than a word. The math italic fonts in cm are only available in two styles medium and bold so there is not a separate choice to be made between bold and bold extended.

Comment: That looks the same for me.

Comment: @Bubaya your example document doesn't use `\log` or `\mathrm` in the scope of `\boldmath`

Comment: OK, now I understand what this command achieves, at least. Then it seems that `\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OT1}{lmr}{b}{it}` works for italics (strangely, not for `cmr`?). What is necessary for `bm` to make it use non-extended letters?